# Publish multiple jar with different version each having separate dependency version

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

I'm creating a library having sub-modules for internal purposes. In one of those sub-module, I am using a spring based dependency. In order to allow the library's client using different spring versions to use the library, I was thinking to provide 2 different versions of the same code with different dependency version compiled (one for Spring 1 and another for Spring 2) and publish the same to mavenLocal.

What is the best way to achieve this (or is there a better way to achieve this for the clients) ? I don't want to maintain another module with same code and just a different dependency version.

- Is it good to have different versions of a dependency in the same project that will be used for creating multiple artifacts?
- If it is ok to do that, how do I create artifacts with different versions and publish them to mavenLocal corresponding to each versioned artifact? (if you can provide the gradle script it'll be really helpful)

I am new to using gradle and it'll be really helpful if someone can guide me for this problem.